# vmwgfx failure on Ubuntu boot

Tags: boot, virtualbox, display

An Ubuntu (64 bit) virtual machine was working on a Windows 10 computer through VM VirtualBox Manager without a problem. Today, suddenly, it gives the error below during the boot.

```
vmwgfx 0000:00:0Z.0 [drm] *ERROR* vmwgfx seems to be running on an unsupported hypervisor.
vmwgfx 0000:00:0Z.0 [drm] *ERROR* This configuration is likely broken.
vmwgfx 0000:00:0Z.0 [drm] *ERROR* Please switch to a supported graphics device to avoid problems.
```

I followed the solutions online (see the links below). Unfortunately, it did not work for me.

- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=110879
- https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/16s6dcl/suddenly_getting_error_vmwgfx_seems_to_be_running/

All the solutions **advise turning off the Windows hypervisor (Hyper-V)** feature. I cannot be sure whether is completely turned off or not. Hope someone can offer another solution here.

Here I uploaded the VBox.Log: https://pastebin.com/ZkXRbJrc

Graphic settings: VMSVGA

**Update:**
The green turtle on the status bar is not showing up. That indicates the Hyper-V is active or not.

Execution engine: VT-x/AMD-V

Graphic driver: Intel UHD Graphics 630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the boot failure. Turns out it was a storage issue. I have been using dynamic storage. After transferring a huge amount of data from host to VM, it got stuck (my theory). I logged in to the computer through ALT+F2 and deleted big chunk files, so the VM started without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

getting log in problems here, when I enter the password of my user the system stays on a blankscreen and doesn't load, using ctrl+f to change the view of the vm works sometimes but not all the times, I don't know if this can be related to the logs mentioned above, but on my boot logs I have the same errors.

- vmwgfx 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* vmwgfx seems to be running on an unsupported hypervisor.

*vmwgfx 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* This configuration is likely broken.

*vmwgfx 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Please switch to a supported graphics device to avoid problems.

I casually have the same GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630

Comment: Have you disabled the hyper-v from system services

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about the *why*, but [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/966411) did the trick for me. I already noticed that installing guest addidtions was'nt working properly with ubuntu without the following packages : `perl`, `gcc` and `dkms`. Apparently, you now need `build-essential` `module-assistant` too.

So,

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install perl gcc dkms build-essential module-assistant
sudo m-a prepare

# *Insert guest additions cd*

sudo mkdir /media/additions/
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/additions
sudo /media/additions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Should be a working procedure.

I need further investigation, but what I feel happens is that the `vboxadd` service soes not launch propery, letting the user stuck on those warnings. Those warnings can be ignored, and does not show the root cause of the problem, which is the Virtualbox additions service not starting properly. Indeed, after 5min or so, the virtual machine finaly launches without further explainations.